# Is it possible to list in mongodb the list of elements whose value is less than 10% of another field?

Tags: mongodb

I basically have a database where I record motorcycles and their mileage.

```
{
 "motorcycle":"A",
 "current_km":4600,
 "review_km":5000
},
{
 "motorcycle":"B",
 "current_km":4000,
 "review_km":5000
},
{
 "motorcycle":"C",
 "current_km":4900,
 "review_km":5000
},
{
 "motorcycle":"D",
  "current_km":3000,
  "review_km":5000
}
```

I have a field called `current_km` that determines your current mileage and I have another field called `review_km`, which consists of specifying the mileage in which your review should be done, as long as your current mileage (`current_km`) is greater than 10% of Mileage review (`review_km`).

So I would like to list the elements where:

`current_km` is greater than:

(`review_km` - ( `review_km` * 0.10))

for example:

```
current_km = 4600;
review_km = 5000;
result = 5000 - (5000 * 0.10);
4600 (current_km)> = 4500 (result) // in this case it is showed
```

In my database it would show the results of motorcycles A and C

how can I do it? I don't know if it is possible to do it in mongodb directly.

Comment: @turivishal  Thanks for your help, I need something like this, but your example will show all records. The condition is only met for the case of motorcycle A and C, therefore only those records should be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use aggregation with `$subtract` and `$multiply`,

- `$addFields` add new fields, we are generating `result` field, equation `(review_km - ( review_km * 0.10))` using `$subtract` and `$multiply`
- `$match` equation in `$expr` if `current_km >= result` if its correct then returns document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      result: {
        $subtract: [
          "$review_km",
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$review_km",
              0.10
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$current_km",
          "$result"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/s2qenvuzLKF

---

#### Shorter version

> If you don't want `result` field in response then combined condition in `$match` and `$addFields` is no longer needed

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$current_km",
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$review_km",
              {
                $multiply: [
                  "$review_km",
                  0.10
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fii__3tTika

Comment: You are a genius and I greatly appreciate your help. Maybe I didn't make myself understood. I don't need it to show motorcycle A or C exactly (in my example the ones that meet the condition are motorcycle A and C, that's why I mentioned them to you).
Based on your code, I just need to show the bikes where `" current_km "` is greater than or equal to `result`

Comment: Updated answer, problem was it is not allowing same generated field in same `$addFields` so thats why added new `$addFields` for second equation

Comment: can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182421/how-can-i-update-a-field-with-2-possible-values-according-to-a-condition