# how can I update a field with 2 possible values according to a condition?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb.

I have a database like this:

```
{
 "universe": "DC",
 "characters": [
 {"name": "superman", "selected": true}, 
 {"name": "wonder woman", "selected": false}, 
 {"name": "flash", "selected": false}
},
{ 
 "universe": "marvel",
 "characters": [
  {"name": "wolverine", "selected": false}, 
  {"name": "cyclops", "selected": false}
}
```

I'm trying to make if the `universe` is "DC", update its `characters` where the character's `name` equals "wonder woman", then I want the belonging `selected` field to be updated to `true` and in this same document, characters that do not match the `name` of "wonder woman" have the value of `false` in `selected`

```
mydb.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
{
  "universe": "DC", //only DC universe
  "characters.name":"wonder woman"   
},
{
  $set: {
    "characters.$.selected": true,  // I dont know how to set false to other objects where name!=wonder woman
  },
})
```

Result desired:

```
 {"name": "superman", "selected": false}, 
 {"name": "wonder woman", "selected": true}, 
 {"name": "flash", "selected": false}
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in MongoDB 3.6, when updating an array field, you can specify [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#update-specific-elements-of-an-array-of-documents) that determine which array elements to update.

```
mydb.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        universe: "DC"
    },
    {
        $set : {
            "characters.$[has].selected" : true,
            "characters.$[not].selected" : false
        }
    },
    { 
        arrayFilters: [ 
            { 
                "has.name": { $eq: "wonder woman" }
            },
            { 
                "not.name": { $ne: "wonder woman" }
            } 
        ],
        returnNewDocument: true
    }
)
```

- The following operation finds a document where the `universe` field equals "DC"
- uses the filtered positional operator `$[<identifier>]` with the `arrayFilters` to modify the `selected` to `true` for all elements in the `characters` array where the `name` *(has.name)* is `$eq` to "wonder women"
- other side the `arrayFilters` to modify the `selected` to `false` for all elements in the `characters` array where the `name` *(not.name)* is `$ne` to "wonder women".
- `returnNewDocument: true` return updated document

Comment: Thank you! again your answers have made me learn a lot. I would like you to clarify this doubt, different from this question. if i wanted to update the name from "superman" to "superman2", is there any way that when that record is updated, the update query will end? or the update query in arrays verifies each one of the elements of an array even if it has already done the update of the registry where it was modified to "superman2"?

Comment: if i understand correctly, You want to know about how update document machination work when array, so basically i don't have core knowledge and Mongodb have't provided any information regarding, but if i say about your superman scenario, update any function will check first parameter that is "where/match" if its match condition `"characters.name": "superman"` then go to further next parameter *(here skipping some parts because it is big to write in comment)* ...

Comment: then next level is `$set` `$push` can update part for this superman scenario it is easy because above condition already got reference of array matched object and with this condition `{ $set: {"characters.$.name" : "superman2"} }` it will update in all collected reference from above match, here no need to use `arrayFilters`., definitely mongodb execution process is very smooth and fast because it deals with json string.

Comment: Exactly there is no documentation that informs me of this. I really appreciate the time you took. so when i update a field inside a nested array, will it stop there, or will it continue with the rest of the records?

in this question he goes through each of the `characters` objects. but is there a scenario where I can ONLY update where the `name`:" wonder woman "and stop there and stop looping around the other objects?

Comment: simple do this for multi update `db.collection.update({"characters.name": "superman"},{"$set": {"characters.$.name": "superman1"}},{multi: true})` or if you have direct _id and want to update single document then use `db.collection.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("123"),"characters.name": "superman"},{"$set": {"characters.$.name": "superman1"}})` and no need worry about looping they have implemented good mechanism behind this.

Comment: I hope I don't bother you anymore. but in our case we don't define `multi: true` and still it goes through each one of all the objects of` characters`

Comment: `multi: true` update all main documents, and here we are updating single main document and multiple sub documents means "characters", if you want to update single sub document then you need to pass unique object "characters._id" or any unique identity for that particular record.

Comment: ok, but assuming that each object within `characters` has an _id, I want to update ONLY the wonder woman object (and I do it using its _id), I understand that each of the` characters` objects will be checked as well. I want to know is if in this case after the "wonder woman" object is updated using its _id, will it continue traversing the rest of the `characters` elements or will it end there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219002/discussion-between-turivishal-and-yavg).

Comment: I put this question that summarizes what I was asking you the other day, it would be great if you could answer it and so that in the future people like me who are not very clear on this topic can understand it.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63210406/how-can-i-make-the-updated-of-mongodb-stop-when-updating-a-field-of-a-nested-a