# How do I update a field in a sub-document array with a field from the document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a large amount of data (~160M items) where a date value wasn't populated on the sub-document array fields, but was populated on the parent document. I'm very new to MongoDB and having trouble figuring out how to $set the field to match. Here's a sample of the data:

```
{
   "_id": "5f11d4c48663f32e940696ed",
   "Widgets":[{
         "WidgetId":663,
         "Name":"Super Widget 2.0",
         "Created":null,
         "LastUpdated":null
      }],
   "Status":3,
   "LastUpdated":null,
   "Created": "2018-11-09T18:22:16.000Z"
   }
}
```

My knowledge of MongoDB is pretty limited but here's the basic aggregation I have created for part of the pipeline and where I'm struggling:

```
db.sample.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "Donors.$.Created" : { 
                    "$exists" : true
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "Widgets.$.Created" : null
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$set" : { 
                "Widgets.$.Created" : "Created"     // <- This is where I can't figure out how to define the reference to the parent "Created" field
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

The desired output would be:

```
{
   "_id": "5f11d4c48663f32e940696ed",
   "Widgets":[{
         "WidgetId":663,
         "Name":"Super Widget 2.0",
         "Created":"2018-11-09T18:22:16.000Z",
         "LastUpdated":null
      }],
   "Status":3,
   "LastUpdated":null,
   "Created": "2018-11-09T18:22:16.000Z"
   }
}
```

Thanks for any assitance

Comment: if you want to update in collection then you can try this `arrayFilters`, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63186367/8987128 you can use in  `updateMany()` function also.

Comment: Interesting, what's the advantage of using that process over an aggregate? With 160million records to update I'm expecting a pretty significant performance hit (230,000 documents, average of 1,000 array items per document)

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! Still I'm extremely new to Mongo and there's no one one my team with any extensive knowledge (won't get into details but it is what it is), and I'm not seeing in the documentation how I would define the value for the Widgets.$.Created field to equal the Created field in the document. If you have time, could you post a possible solution? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you attempting to add the `Created` field to sub documents on query/aggregation? Or are you attempting to update/save the `Created` field on the subdocuments?

The $ is an update operator, to be used with updateMany or updateOne. Not aggregate.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-array/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

If you just want to add the parents `Created` field to all subdocuments on query/aggregation this is all you have to do: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yHDHULCSTIz

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Widgets.Created": "$Created"
    }
  }
])
```

If your attempting to save the parents `Created` field to all subdocuments:

```
db.sample.updateMany({"Widgets.Created" : null}, [{$set: {"Widgets.Created" : "$Created"}}])
```

Note: This matches any doc that has a subdocument with a null `Created` field and updates all the subdocuments.

Comment: I'm attempting to save the parents' `Created` field to the sub-document associated, but when I attempted to use the query provided I got the following error: `Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators`. The sub-documents all have a `Created` field that is null after a data migration from MariaDB to MongoDB. The parent Document's `Created` field is a valid date that I can use to populate the sub-document field

Comment: Did you include the $set part? The array wrapping the update is is important too

Comment: `db.getCollection("sandbox.sample").updateMany({"Widgets.Created": null}, [{$set: {"Widgets.Created" : "$Created"}}]);` That's the query I ran that generated the error. I'm using `MongoDB 4.2.2`

Comment: @KevinO. Where are you executing this query? try to execute in mongo shell, because might be mongo 3t or robo mongo or studio 3t will not support this query in shell.

Comment: Yes, I've tested in 4.2.2 and 4.0 in shell, both worked. Thanks @turivishal

Comment: I am using Studio 3T's intellishell, will try in shell directly

Comment: Found the issue, and it now works in both shell and Studio 3T: `db.getCollection("sandbox.sample").update({"Widgets.Created": null}, [{$set: {"Widgets.Created" : "$Created"}}], {multi: true});` The {multi: true} was missed which prevented it from working in S3T, and successfully updated each document in the sample set.